# why do merged questions remain on the unanswered list?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've noticed that there's currently [a question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5016/affordable-medium-format-slr) on the [unanswered](https://photo.stackexchange.com/unanswered) section of the site that is listed as having been merged with [another question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5014/affordable-entry-level-medium-format), because it is a duplicate.  This makes it impossible to answer (at least with my current reputation), or even comment on (and I have enough to do that, in theory), and it doesn't have any answers which can be voted on... so...  why does it remain in the unanswered section?  Wouldn't it be better to have it get removed from such queries, even if it isn't wholly removed from the site?

I think of the unanswered section to be my go-to point for questions I can potentially answer.  And since the site won't let me do that with this one, it's frustrating to have it show up there.

Am I missing something?

I'm *guessing* this is a bug, so tagging as such.  Please feel free to re-categorize as more experienced-with-the-site folks deem appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because questions aren't automatically closed when they're merged -- now closed as a duplicate, and it shouldn't show up anymore...

Comment: Indeed it is now absent from the unanswered section.  Thank you, Rowland!